# Constructors: do Instance variables store separate values for objects?

Tags: java

Suppose we initialize the instance variables with some values, and then again initialize them inside a constructor with some other values, so does that mean that variables will hold separate values for objects regardless of what we initialized them to outside the constructor? For example:

```
class A {
    int a = 2;

    A(int p) {
        a = p;
    }

    public void Foo(String args[]) {
        A obj = new A(5);
    }
}
```

In the above code, do 'a' and 'obj.a'  hold seperate values?

Comment: What does `a` by itself refer to? Or rather, *which* `a` does it refer to?

Comment: Have you tried to check the values yourself?

Comment: In this case, `A.a` will return `2` only if it's initialized with the default constructor (which you didn't wrote)

Comment: @MatheusCirillo how would he possibly call A.a since the variable is not static?

Comment: There is only one `a` per instance of `A`, so it can only hold one value at a time. The statement `a = p` implicitly means `this.a = p`, and it replaces the initial value of `2`. The value of `obj.a` is 5, and the initial value `2` is gone.

Comment: `int a = 2;` is simply a short-cut, which inserts `a = 2;` after `super()` in your constructors for you. At the byte-code level, your current constructor is indistinguishable from `A(int p) { super(); this.a = 2; this.a = p; }`

Comment: I tried and they print separate values for a and obj.a. What I want to actually know is that, is this the way all constructors work( default, Non parameterized, parameterized)? I actually have a bit of confusion about how constructors work.

Comment: What I can't understand is that, can an already initialized variable hold a separate value for an object?

Comment: The constructor of a class is called when you create an instance of this class. Every class has built-in (even you do not declared it - default / non-parameters constructor) and you can create a constructor that you can pass parameters to iitialize the instance variables of the object you create. In case you just use the no-argument constructor, the instance of your class you create will have the efault values of the class(in your example a = 2)

Comment: @NickAth it's just a notation. I'm just pointing out that the attribute `a` inside `A` will print 2 only if the default constructor is called.

Comment: @NickAth The default constructor only exists if there is no explicit constructor defined.

Answer (score 1):

> In the above code, do 'a' and 'obj.a' hold seperate values?

Yes.  `obj.a` holds the value 5, while `a` holds the value "there isn't any such variable and there's no meaningful answer to what its value is."

There is no `a` by itself, only the value of `a` associated with a *particular* instance of the class `A`.